# WSDL off ServiceStack REST API

Tags: servicestack

I know this at least IMO is a stupid request.  Because WSDL is old hat and sucks compared to just doing a RESTful API.  But I have a corporate "mandate" where we want to do a REST API but then corporate wants a WSDL still.  I know..it makes no sense and apparently we can't push back and say NO and tell them to just use our future REST API.

So **can you generate a WSDL if I were to start creating a REST API with ServiceStack**?  Meaning I add uri attributes and such? So that I can "make them happy"?

I prefer not to use WCF, it's a nightmare with a ton of attributes and configuration to try and hack a RPC style web service to try and be RESTful.  Obviously that doesn't work out too well.

Comment: did you finally do that? what were your experiences? would be great to hear anything from you!

Comment: Yup I feel you.  We have corporate mandates for some instances as well.  The architect should be fired.

Answer (score 2):

SOAP along with REST is supported and you can have REST API along with soap wsdl. There are some recommendations posted in [servicestack wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) that you can review and get started! You just need to implement the restful service and soap, json, xml etc are automatically supported.